# Why is my form being re-rendered wiht a '<div class="field_with_errors">' element?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.  I have this for displaying a field in my form

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price, 'Price', :class => "control-label" %> <span class="required">*</span> <br>
    <%= f.text_field :price, :size => 30 %>
    <div class='error'><%= show_errors(@user_event, :price) %></div>
  </div>
```

It renders the HTML as below

```
<div class="field">
    <label class="control-label" for="user_event_price">Price</label> <span class="required">*</span> <br>
    <input size="30" name="user_event[price]" id="user_event_price" type="text">
    <div class="error"></div>
  </div>
```

Everything looks and works great until an error occurred and the form is re-rendered with the error.  Then the HTML is rendered as

```
<div class="field">
    <div class="field_with_errors"><label class="control-label" for="user_event_price">Price</label></div> <span class="required">*</span> <br>
    <div class="field_with_errors"><input size="30" value="" name="user_event[price]" id="user_event_price" type="text"></div>
    <div class="error">Please enter a value for price.</div>
  </div>
```

The only reason this is a problem is because my asterisk "*", then appears below the label element (they are on different lines), which looks ugly.  I'm wondering if this is because the form is re-rendered with that strange

```
<div class="field_with_errors">
```

element.  How can I get my form to re-render without that upon an error?  Below, if it even matters, is my "show_errors" function defined in my application_helper.rb file ...

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def show_errors(object, field_name)
    if object.errors.any?
      if !object.errors.messages[field_name].blank?
        object.errors.messages[field_name].join(", ")
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your `show_errors` method. This is a built-in behavior of Rails' form builder.

Comment: How do I disable this behavior?

Comment: See the linked duplicate.

Comment: You're going to make me work for this one, aren't ya?  Well here goes.

Comment: I'm not trying to make you "work for it", I'm telling you exactly where to find the information you need.